# Windows Store App Set TextBlock Visibility Based on Child Control Content

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-store-apps

I want to set visibility of a TextBlock based on whether or not a child has a value.  How can I accomplish this?

```
<TextBlock Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, 
Path=Child[1].Text, Converter={StaticResource visiblityConverter}}" 
Style="{StaticResource BodyTextStyle}"  Margin="2,1,1,1" >
  <Bold xml:space="preserve">Player 2: </Bold>
  <Run Text="{Binding Player2Name}" />
</TextBlock>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TextBlock` is `not a panel` hence it doesn't have any `Child` property which you can bind to.

Instead you should use `ElementName` for your binding. Give `x:Name` to `Run` and bind to it like this -

```
<TextBlock Visibility="{Binding Path=Text, ElementName=runText,
                          Converter={StaticResource visiblityConverter}}">
    <Bold xml:space="preserve">Player 2: </Bold>
    <Run x:Name="runText" Text="{Binding Player2Name}" />
</TextBlock>
```